# How to create buttons dynamicly based on file/folder structure in android

Tags: android

im new to android and im trying to make a "simple" app.
However i would like to know if, what i have planned, is possible in android.

Basicly it's a crude database reader/navigator.

I made a folder structure in the assets folder with a few directories and *.txt files.
Now the plan is to read/scan the folder structure on startup of the program and dynamicly create buttons labeld  based on the folder,- and file names.
The buttons have to link to the files and folders so the user can navigate the folder structure and open a *.txt file and read it. Also the idea is that the buttons reflect the folder structure as it is in the assets folder.

The idea is that the user can easly retrieve info from the app and i can add info to the app trough *.txt files  and adjust the structure just by adding/removing directories and files in the assets folder.

i am using android studio but like i already say'd: i am a beginner with programming and would like to know if this is even possible with android.
And if it is: could someone please tell me how i should start this project or link me to some example code on how this could be done?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes it is possible with Android. In case you want to know more, please search for 'File Managers' on Google Play Store and check out the top apps.

[Here](https://github.com/1hakr/AnExplorer) is an open-source File Manager (Android) for you to explore.

[Here](http://custom-android-dn.blogspot.in/2013/01/create-simple-file-explore-in-android.html) is a tutorial on creating custom file explorer.

FYI - Please do some research on Google before directly posting a question on SO. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If i read your idea correctly, what you are trying to achieve is very much possible. I would start looking at the `AssetManager` class and I believe what you are looking for is the `list()` command which should give you what you need.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html

You can obtain the `AssetManager` from everywhere within your app through the `Context` object which you will find to be everywhere around. ;)

From there on you can build your hierarchy and open files.

There are some useful wizard projects in Android studio, which will basically setup a general structure of an Android App. I would recommend starting with a Single Activity application and move on from there.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like ListView is something that could be beneficial for you here. ListView allows you to dynamically create buttons, or whatever you need. ListView has the added advantage that you can use an XML file to inform the ListView of how to display the buttons, images or whatever you want to display for each element of the list. There are loads of videos demonstrating how to use ListView, but here is a link to its documentation: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html

Also, if you'd like a structured way of learning how to develop apps, I'd recommend the Android courses on Udacity to help you out.

Best of luck!